# Calling action from command

Tags: symfony, command, action

I want to perform an action from a custom command. The forward method Controller.php class provides this function, but I do not know access it from the execute () method of the command file

Answer (score 7):

Making the controller a service will result in performance overhead because of the request stack, as it then should return a `HttpResponse`. The `Request` scope will not be very usefull in the command.

I'd advise you to refactor the action from the Controller to a separate service class definition, and get that class from the container in both the controller and the command by making it a `ContainerAwareCommand`.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Answer (score 4):

Use controller as service [How to Define Controllers as Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)

Comment: It is precisely with this solution that I need to use forward.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to call a controller action from a command then you'll need to set up the controller (and subsequently the request for the controller) in your command code.

If you have a look in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` then you'll see that the `forward()` method duplicates the current `Request` object and then sends it through the `HttpKernel`. As Commands don't use HttpKernel, this kind of forwarding won't work.

Depending on what your action does, you might just be able to do:

```
$controller = new Your\Controller();
$controller->yourAction();
```

If your action requires a request then:

```
$request = Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
$controller = new Your\Controller();
$controller->setContainer($this->getContainer()); // from the ContainerAwareCommand interface
$controller->yourAction($request);
```

By the sounds of it this isn't going to do what you want so there are a couple of ways forward:

1. Turn your controller into a service, this is described in [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and will mean that your controller and action can be summoned directly from the container that your command (probably) has set up. This handles dependencies that your controller and actions may have.
2. Split out the functionality that you need from your action into its own class or service. This is the better way forward as if you're calling the same bit of code in two places it makes sense to centralise it somewhere.

Comment: It's the way 1 I have experienced, but it requires the use of the method 'forward' in the 'execute' function of the command file. It appears,that  this method 'forward' only works in controllers