# How do I call a controller action from within a command in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, post

I am working on an application which serves as an API. I have implemented a POST method for adding records to a table in the application.

I also have a command which is to be run daily - is there a way to call my POST API method internally from within my command? Or do I just call it via the application URL?

I am using Symfony 3.4.6.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: You can schedule a cron job to call your action with `curl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling action from command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512200/calling-action-from-command)

Comment: The url approach is perhaps the cleanest but you could also move the add record functionality into it's own service and then call the service from both the controller as well as the command.

Comment: like Cerad wrote is the way how do to it. a real cronjob works from the console and not through an url, Make a service that does the work and call that service from controller and from the console command class: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Symfony `kernel` to execute HTTP requests.

You can use the same kernel of the Console, or create a new one (if you must change environnement).

```php
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$kernel = new Kernel('prod', false);
$request = Request::create('/toto', 'GET');
$response = $kernel->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, false);

die($response->getContent());
```

(tested with Symfony 5).

Comment: Kernel est abstract in symfony 4

Comment: I'm on version 6 and I was able to inject HttpKernelInterface

Comment: hey @SubOne I think you can add a new answer specifically for version 6

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the symfony/console component:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html